# Read integer statement

Tags: fortran90

I am quite new with fortran and have a question. I need to read 2 integers from the following line:

```
K=234, L=241, I=0
```

I am not interested in the last value. Just need the integers 234 and 241. I tried it with

```
read(20,'(3X,I3,3X,I3)')a,b
```

It compiles, but when I run the program I always get the error message:

```
At line 27 of file test.f90 (unit = 20, file = 'int_p2.dat')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

You have strings in your line, so your `READ` statement ought to account for it. You should replace it with

```
  READ(20, '(3(a2,i3,2x))') dumChar, k, dumChar, l, dumInt, dumChar
```

where `dumChar` is a character of length 2 and `dumInt` is an integer.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see a problem in your code. (off course, your format is wrong, but should not give runtime error). Also, you are escaping chars (K,L) rather then reading them. compiler should not complain. but `3X` will eat up 1 integer for `K=234`

```
Program  se
Implicit None
integer :: K,L,I,a,b

open(20, file="se.in",status='old')
read(20,'(3X,I3,3X,I3)')a,b
close(20)
write(*,*)a,b
End Program  se


$ cat se.in 
K=234, L=241, I=0

$gfortran se.f90
$ ./a.out 
          34         241
```

If you still getting the problem, and if this are one single line you are trying to read, do 
**remove any space before `K=` in the file.**
I think this is the error, as the code is reading non-integer.

Comment: I have just shown him that his format is not giving any runtime error if he start the input file from the first column. possibly its not clear to you or you have not read it completely.